# How do I disable ASP.NET Core's "Razor Pages"?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

We use ASP.NET Core's "MVC", but not the new ["Razor Pages"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/).

I know they get served from `/Pages` by default, so **at runtime (!!)** I dropped some razor pages in there to see what would happen - and to my surprise they were served without doing anything futher!

This is a major security risk for us. On the production server, some malicious actor could drop razor pages into the correct directory, and then do considerable damage.

I assumed they could be disabled, but found nothing about this.

How can I completely disable "Razor Pages"?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be disabled, but ... if someone has filesystem access to your server, you have bigger problems. They could as well overwrite your site's DLLs.

Comment: @CodeCaster That is true, but that may not be what they want to do. Besides, why do that when they can just add a text file to the site, get some stuff, then delete the file... quick and easy. In shared hosting you don't have control over the production machine, so this is a real problem, not theoretical. I agree with you though.

Comment: Yeah but apart from Razor pages, they could as well drop a `Global.asax` which gets run on _every_ request. So while I agree this is a real problem and not a theoretical one, it's not one you can easily circumvent. As soon as some malicious actor has access to your server, there's pretty much close to nothing you can do to protect your site against them.

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow forgot that `Global.asax` was still used in Core! Your comment just made my paranoia 10x worse! Thanks! :-)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the situation where I am able to drop in a Razor page at runtime **when the application has been published** without receiving compilation errors. And I’m pretty sure a `Global.asax` should not run..? ASP.NET Core does not know about it, so it’s only IIS that could use it, but that shouldn’t happen when the application pool is unmanaged, should it? – But yeah, this “risk” is very hypothetical. It’s much easier to just replace the whole app with something else, or worse…

Comment: Global.asax isn't used in ASP.NET Core applications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments above by @CodeCaster say they can't be disabled, so I thought of a hacky workaround - change the directory to something random:

```
services
  .AddMvc();
  .WithRazorPagesRoot("/" + generateRandomString());
```

This isn't foolproof though - it won't stop someone who is determined enough to mess with your dlls.

*(If they can be disabled, add your answer and I'll accept it.)*